# Update ListView item outside of adapter

Tags: android

I have a ListView where each item represents a podcast. Selecting an item plays the podcast.  While playing, the view for that ListView item displays an elapsed time counter with a SeekBar next to it to show progress.

Where I'm having a problem is figuring out how to handle updating the elapsed time counter (a TextView) while the SeekBar is being repositioned by touch.  Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` during the `onProgressChanged` SeekBar event doesn't seem to work very well.

Comment: Could you show some of your code and the item's layout?  Are you extending a ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Also, is the user able to play more than one at a time or is there only one playing at anytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of this UI pattern, simply because if the user scrolls, they may have difficulty finding where they were again. I would recommend having your `SeekBar` and counter, plus information about the podcast currently playing, outside of the `ListView` -- perhaps in a layout that is set to have visibility `GONE` and is animated in when the user chooses a podcast.

Lacking that, I think you are in for a fair amount of coding pain.

You are correct that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is probably not the answer. Instead, you will probably need to work with the `TextView` directly...while it is on-screen. Tracking when it is and is not on-screen is the job of your `Adapter`, though the details would vary significantly depending on how you are actually implementing the list (e.g., different view types for the rows?).

Comment: +1 - this sounds like the *wrong* way to code a music player UI.

Comment: I did not realize what I was getting myself into by allowing the audio to be played directly from the ListView.  This is my first real Android app and it has been a good learning experience.  I think launching a new activity to play a selected podcast would have been a better approach.  Thanks for your input.